# SQL Server : duplicating a table with data results in constrain violation, how?

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, constraints, primary-key, unique-constraint

I am trying to duplicate a SQL Server database to a new server.

I scripted the table creates and then used the Import/Export to transfer data from one database to another.

This worked fine for all but two tables which threw errors for primary key violations!!!

So, I'm trying to figure our how that happens. I used the SQL Server Management Studio to script the tables in both the source and target databases to ensure they are identical which, no surprise, they are. Both tables have an identity column so I made sure to tick the check boxes for "Delete rows in destination table" as well as "Enable Identity Insert". The second of course to ensure relational integrity with the other ported data.

So how does this happen?  Here are the two table creates and errors just to give you the details but regardless of the details of the table I don't understand how the data can exist in version of the table and cause a constraint violation in the other.

Can anyone give me an alternative way to export/import the table structure and data to get the two tables over from one DB to the other??

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PageHeader](
    [PageHeaderID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SiteKey] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Page] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [TitleTag] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [DescriptionTag] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [Keywords] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [ContentGroup] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LastModified] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [LastChecked] [smalldatetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PageHeader_key0] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PageHeaderID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

- Copying to [dbo].[PageHeader] (Error)
Messages
```

> Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been terminated.".
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.PageHeader' with unique index 'PageHeader_key1'. The duplicate key value is (1, search.aspx?Q=Franck M).".
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.    > The "Destination - PageHeader.Inputs[Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "Destination - PageHeader.Inputs[Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - PageHeader" (43) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (56). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Keywords](
    [KeywordID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SiteKey] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [SearchEngine] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,      
    [Keywords] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [Keywords_key0] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [KeywordID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

- Copying to [dbo].[Keywords] (Error)
Messages
```

> Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "The statement has been terminated.".
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Keywords' with unique index 'Keywords_key1'. The duplicate key value is (1, Google.co.jp, ?????????  200/mab137r).".
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Destination - Keywords.Inputs[Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "Destination - Keywords.Inputs[Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - Keywords" (28) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (41). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc02020c4: Data Flow Task 1: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source - Keywords returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: New database case sensitive perhaps? Different collation?

Comment: Why not backing up your database and then restore it on the other server or just detached/stop sql server and copy the database files and attached the copy on the other server.

Comment: The PKs are created as `PageHeader_key0` and `Keywords_key0`, but the error message is for constraints named `PageHeader_key1` and `Keywords_key1`. Are you sure your source and destination are set up correctly?

Comment: Aaron - great suggestion but...the collation is identical: "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS".

Comment: Ralf - I had not noticed this BUT I have checked again and the tables are the same.  I used Management Studio's option to "Script table as..." and grabbed the creates from both source and destination and put them through DIFF which came back with NO differences.  Not even the names of the PKs differ so...very interesting catch on your part but I can't see why the DB would report the errors with those names....very strange.  Is there a way I can query for those constraint names to see if they exist somewhere in the DB???

Comment: Jade, yes that would certainly be the logical and easiest solution BUT I am going TO Amazon RDS which does NOT allow restore from backup, so one has to do something like bulk copy or Imports / Export ... *SIGH*

Comment: Ralf, I ran the query below and got back two constraints that are not even close and on completely separate tables and then the "Keywords_key0" constraint which matches both the source and target creates so...I have no where the DB is coming up with Keywords_key1:

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS NameofConstraint,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName,
OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS TableName,
type_desc AS ConstraintType
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT' AND OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%Keyword%'

Same results for PageHeader: "PageHeader_key0" yes,  NO "PageHeader_key1"